# Summation of n terms of a series$ 1+2+8+64+.........$

Tags: computational-mathematics

In one of my problem , I got a series as $1$,$2$,$8$,$64$,$1024$...and so on. can we really get a sum expression for that series$???$

If yes, then what is the expression **$f$** $?$
or the sum of $n$ terms of a series 
$$1+2+8+64+1024+......+2^{n(n+1)/2}$$
What is the procedure to get expression??

Comment: There isn't a closed form using plain arithmetic. The last term is far too big compared to the previous ones.

Comment: There is [apparently](https://oeis.org/A181388) a recurrence: $a(n) = a(n-1) +  \dfrac{2(a(n-1) -a(n-2))^2}{a(n-2) - a(n-3)} $

Comment: @Henry. Could you explain how you did arrive to this nice result ? It is quite impressive.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: not mine but Robert Israel's at [OEIS A181388](https://oeis.org/A181388)